# Distributed Caching for frequently changing data

Tags: .net, wcf, caching

I want to pool my connection objects (not SQL connection objects) across multiple instances of my service (specifically, my service will be deployed on a web farm and all instances will manage a common pool). These objects will be updated frequently. I also want to persist my connection objects so that I can recover them in case an instance goes down.


Any solutions (out-of-the-box or otherwise) or suggestions which will help me achieve this?


So far I have come across EntLib Caching Block with Data Access Block to persist data. However, Caching block is not recommended for frequently changing data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on such matters, particularly for rapidly changing data (there's often little benefit in caching it!), but...

I believe the Enterprise Library Caching Block is deprecated as it's being brought into .NET [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664753%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx)

You could have a look at [Microsoft Server AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise Cache is a very simple key value store. it doesn't have the capabilities to sync remote instance and you will be doing a lot of work yourself. though as far as i know it has no problem with frequently changed data ( at last not in a reservation project i did long ago ). if you are making a more robust system i would recommend to use more advance caching that allow you to have one central caching instance with multiple remote reference, each holding the entire set of data. this is a page that describe such a solution : 
http://wiki.gigaspaces.com/wiki/display/XAP9NET/Local+Cache

another option if you want to use DB and avoid cache is trying to use NHibernate with second level cache. it means you need to configure it at every instance and refresh it a lot. maybe  lesser option compare to a full blown caching.